# Why is complex multiplication of an elliptic curve called complex multiplication?

Tags: terminology, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a field $k$. Let $\text{End}_k(E)$ denote the endomorphism ring of $E$, i.e.,
$$\text{End}_k(E) = \{\text{base point preserving morphism} \ f:E \to E\}.$$

Since multiplication by an integer $n$ is an endomorphism of $E$, we have an embedding
$$ \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \text{End}_k(E).$$

If this is a proper embedding, then we say the elliptic curve $E$ has complex multiplication.

Why is it called complex multiplication? Does it have anything to do with multiplication by a complex number?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_multiplication) does a good job explaining the origin of the term in the context of elliptic curves. Anyway, it comes from the description of an elliptic curve (over $\Bbb{C}$) in the form $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice in the complex plane. Should $\Lambda$ be closed under multiplication by a complex number (other than a rational integer), then that number is necessarily an integer in an imaginary quadratic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$, and also naturally gives rise to an endomorphism of the quotient space $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But I didn't see any explanation there.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I didn't see you explanation just now. So a simple example will be $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}[i]$, then multiplying by $i$ preserve $\Lambda$ and hence induces an endomorphism of $E = \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$.

Comment: The point is that when $x\Lambda\subseteq\Lambda$ for some $x\in\Bbb{C}\setminus\Bbb{Z}$, then multiplication by $x$ on $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$ is well defined. This is always the case when $x$ is an algebraic integer of a field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$, and $\Lambda$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Correct, that's the idea. You get a bit more variety, when the class number of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ is $h>1$. But I'm the wrong person to explain such subtleties.